# UWP Pivot swipe gesture not working

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

To support Windows 10 desktop I ported my Windows 8.1 WinRT application with the [Project Converter](https://github.com/Win10DevGuideMVA/ProjectUpgradeUtility) to a universal application. On a touch device (e.g. MS Surface) everything works as well as on the Windows 8.1 WinRT application version. But on my PC I am not able to provide any input. (Except mouse clicks) The pivot control doesn't trigger any swipe gesture (made with the mouse) and clicking on the headers (PivotItems) also doesn't change the current selected pivot item. All interactions are enabled as follows:

[image]

Xaml as follows:

```
<Pivot Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle}"
       IsHitTestVisible="True" IsTabStop="True">                
    <PivotItem Header="Game" IsTabStop="True">
```

How am I able to listen to mouse swipe gestures? Do I have to listen manually and trigger the events on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot swipe gesture is only working on touch devices. You have to write your own code to make this happen in all devices.